# simplecursoradapter updates views randomly

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a ListView in the activity. Data for ListView is populated from Contacts using SimpleCursorAdapter. The layout for ListView's row is two TextViews representing person name and number, and an ImageView for which visibility is set to invisible.

I have custom ViewBinder for the adapter, which checks if ImageView should be visible or not. The problem is that image is visible randomly. I guess the problem is in ViewHolder pattern that SimleCursorAdapter's implementation use with newView and bindView.

Can I solve the problem without writing custom cursor adapter or not?

Source below:

**list_row.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/directory_pushed"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:text="contact name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_name"
        android:text="093797888" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_phone"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Contacts.java**

```
public class Contacts extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, ViewBinder {

    private ListView mContactList;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<String> contacts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts);

        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                Phone.NUMBER };
        String selection = Phone.TYPE + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { String
                .valueOf(Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) };
        String sortOrder = Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

        contacts = LoginInfo.getContacts(this);

        Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

        mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_row,
                managedCursor, new String[] { Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER,
                        Phone.NUMBER }, new int[] { R.id.contact_name,
                        R.id.contact_number, R.id.selected }, 0);

        mAdapter.setViewBinder(this);

        mContactList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        mContactList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        LoginInfo info = LoginInfo.getLoginInfo(this);
        info.contacts = null;
        info.contacts = contacts;

        LoginInfo.updateCache(this, info);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.selected) {
            String number = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            if (isSelected(number)) {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean isSelected(String number) {
        int index = contacts.indexOf(number);
        return !(index == -1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        Cursor c = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);

        String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));

        contacts.add(number);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion creating custom adapter is simpler but If You wish to keep it that way try this

```
@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.selected) {
        String number = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        if (isSelected(number)) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it works. in the Contacts.java i've added a line `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to see the change instanly. also i don't think that creating custom implementation for CursorAdapter is good design in this case. don't like to have many un-reusable essences, if you know what i mean. :D

Comment: Glad to be of help. As about custom adapters if You prefer that way go with it. I prefer to write my own adapters because it keeps the view logic for my list in separate file and makes activity class code clearer. That only is case if my list elements may have different views.

Comment: well, i don't know if it is correct, "android way", but i prefer to use built-ins till the end. as i'm newbie, could you please advise if i'm right? i mean, if it is good design or not. if there is something that framework provides why should i override it, why should i reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I don't know what is commonly known good practice for this case and I am not saying Yours is wrong. Writing custom adapter is not reinventing a wheel but extending/upgrading it. If You want to know my personal opinion I wrote a post on blog about [writing custom adapter](http://www.gustekdev.com/2013/05/custom-cursoradapter-and-why-not-use.html).